# Keep windows contents ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I want to have multiple full terminal windows with ncurses, and be able to switch the window.

Pseudo code:

```
write "Hello" in window 1
switch to window 2 and write "Hi"
go back to window 1 and write "how are you?"
```

The problem is that the initial "Hello" is cleared while writing "Hi" in window 2.
How to escape this to have at the end "Hello how are you?" in window 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, can't debug pseudocode.

Comment: You will receive far more assistance if you paste in the code that you have so far that isn't quite working right.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for this problem is that running `wgetch` on a window does a corresponding [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) on the same window.  As a special, but frequent case, [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) refreshes the standard screen `stdscr`:

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to  **wrefresh**,  **wrefresh**  will  be
>   called before another character is read.

The exact nature of the conflicting refreshes depends on the actual program, of course.

The [`panel`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) library is recommended for solving this problem in general.  You can (with some care) work around the problem using [`touchwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_touch.3x.html) before getting characters from the window to which your program switches focus.  If this is done when switching focus (for input) between windows, it works reasonably well.  However, a few possible issues come to mind:

- if the input is from *one* window, and *both* are being updated — but they overlap — the obscured portion of the other window will not be seen.
- if the repainting is done for example to show status from two processes (rather than waiting for input), the competing `wrefresh`'s can be slow as well as distracting.

Comment: Thanks, i tried touchwin() and it works. What kind of problems may appear with touchwin()? why did you say "with some care"?